# ¿Porque la respuesta de ajax es un objecto [duplicado ]del resultado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, programacion-asincrona

Mi código que utilizo es el sgt:

```
(function( $ ){

    "use strict";

    let  title, a = [], text;
    $(document).on('sf:ajaxfinish', '.searchandfilter', function(){
    
    
                // Referencias al html
                let span  = $('#resultados p span.filtro');
                let input = $('.searchandfilter input:checked');
                let inputText = $('.searchandfilter input.sf-input-text');
                let select = $('.searchandfilter :selected');
        
                console.log({input});
                console.log({select});
                console.log({span});
                console.log({inputText});
                console.log(typeof input);
                console.log(typeof select);
                console.log(typeof inputText);
        
        
                setTimeout(function() { 
                 
                    console.log("ajax complete");
                
                   
                    // Evaluando el campo input text
                    $('.searchandfilter input.sf-input-text').each(function(){
                        text = $(this).val();
                        title = $(this).parent();
        
                        if ( text != '') { // si no esta vacío
                            a.push(title.text());
                            a.push(text);
                             
                         }
                         return a;
                    });
                    
                    // Evaluando que existe el campos input que se encuentran dentro de los li 
                    input.each(function() {
                        title = $(this).parent().text();
                        
                        if($(this).length  > 0){
                            a.push(title); 
                           // console.log(input.val());
                        }
                        return a;
                    });
                    
                    
                    // Campos select chequeados
                    select.each(function() {
                        
                        title = $(this).parent().parent();
                        //console.log(`Esta en blanco el valor de los  select ${ $(elemento).val() == '' }`);
                        //console.log(`El texto del select en blanco es: ${ $(elemento).text() }`);
                        //console.log(`El valor del select en blanco es: ${ $(elemento).val() }`);
                        a.push(title.find('span').text()); 
                        console.log($(this).val() === 'Selecciona');
    
                        if(($(this).val() === '') && ($(this).val() === 'Selecciona')){
                            
                            console.log($(this).text());
                        } else {
                            a.push($(this).text());
                        }
        
                    });
    
                    
                   
                    console.log({a}); 
    
   
                    return span.text(a);
                   
            }, 1000);
          

        });
    
}(jQuery));
```

Lo que me pasa aquí es que la respuesta me llega duplicada y no se como hacer para que me llegue un solo objeto no dos, esta es la respuesta que me da:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado que se me guarda en el array a tiene 32 elementos adentro y son repetidos todos no se cuantas veces, alguna ayuda, por favor? Alguna idea de porque me pasa esto? yo probé solo agregando esta función así:

```
$(document).on('sf:ajaxfinish', '.searchandfilter', function(){
       console.log($(this));
 });
```

y así es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que me pasa ya desde el inicio sin todavía hacer nada. Aquí lo que estoy recibiendo es la respuesta del Ajax y me la devuelve duplicada en dos objetos y no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, o a lo mejor no entiendo bien la respuesta, no lo se la verdad. Agradecería cualquier idea. Gracias

Comment: No hay nada raro, por lo que lo más seguro es que el evento se dispara dos veces. Quizás otra parte de tu código esté modificando el DOM o que tengas el mismo *script* referenciado dos veces...

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo comprobar que el evento se dispara dos veces?